# Can't Access Quote from checkout session after returning from payment Gateway

Tags: checkout, quote, payment-gateway

I am building payment gateway extension and i am facing small issue to get the quote object after control return from payment Gateway.

Let me explain you in detail.

I am using below funtion to redirect to payment gateway.

```
public function getCheckoutRedirectUrl()
{
return Mage::getUrl('custom/index/start');
}
```

Above method works fine. I am redirecting to payment gateway and payment processed successful with success message and redirect back to our store with captured status on below controller action.

```
public function returnAction()
{
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->collectTotals();
$payment = $quote->getPayment();
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
$quote->save();
$order = $service->getOrder();
$this->getSession()->setLastQuoteId($quote->getId())
->setLastSuccessQuoteId($quote->getId())
->setLastOrderId($order->getId());
{
```

Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT:
break;
case Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING:
case Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE:
case Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW:
$order->sendNewOrderEmail();
break;
}
$this->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage/success'));
return;
}

But in the above function i get the quote object as blank and due to that i am unable to place an order. This means that after returning from payment gateway it clears the checkout session.

How can i get the quote object and what is the problem ?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

***After click on place order button  at  final step of checkout*** ,you can not get  quote object from  `$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();`

As per as magento,whenever a customer is click on place order button  then a quote is convert to order object and unlink the session quote object from session. and just assign:

- `last quote id` to checkout session variable to `last_quote_id`
- Newly created `order increment id` to session variable
  `last_real_order_id`

If you want to get  **order increment id & quote id** then use 
`$OrderIncrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();` and 
`$quote=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastQuoteId()`  respectively at returnAction

```
$OrderObject=$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$order->loadByIncrementId($OrderIncrementId);
```

And

```
$QuoteObject = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$QuoteObject->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastQuoteId());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am using below function means 

public function getCheckoutRedirectUrl()
{
return Mage::getUrl('custom/index/start');
}

when i click on save payment then i am redirected to payment gateway.
Same function as paypal standard payment Gateway.

I have tried code but its not working and redirect back to return action and redirected to shopping cart page with blank cart.

I got quote object as blank value.

Let me know